# Is it possible to have jsx files inside tsx and avoid the errors?

Tags: typescript

I am migrating to tsx, and I am wondering if it is possible to "ignore" the jsx files so I do not have to go all the way down in the hierarchy and rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to ignore .jsx files and prevent TypeScript from checking them during compilation.

To exclude .jsx files from the compilation process add the following line to your `compilerOptions` object:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.jsx" // exclude .jsx files
  ]
}
```